# How scroll rows and columns in grid with cocos2d-js

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I new in the game dev and cocos.
So, I have following grid:

```
1|2|3|4
5|6|7|8
9|1|2|3
```

User can scroll row or columns around.
For example, if user scroll first row by one position we got following grig:

```
4|1|2|3
5|6|7|8
9|1|2|3
```

How I can do in with cocos2d js? Which components use for that?

Now I try create grid:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            var tile = new NumberTile(i);
            tile.pictureValue = gameArray[i];
            this.addChild(tile, 0);
            tile.setPosition(49 + i % 4 * 74, 400 - Math.floor(i / 4) * 74);
}
```

And add to game Layer.
NumberTile - its sprite with number. But I don't know how to scroll rows and columns around.

Answer (score 0):

use a vertical scrollview as container, add add horizontal scrollviews into it.

`var HelloWorldLayer = cc.Layer.extend({
    sprite: null,
    ctor: function() {
        // 1. super init first
        this._super();
        var count = 10;
        var size = cc.winSize;
        var w = size.width;
        var h = size.height / 4;
        var c_container = new cc.Node();
        c_container.setContentSize(cc.size(w, h * count));
        var container = new cc.ScrollView(size, c_container);
        container.setDirection(cc.SCROLLVIEW_DIRECTION_VERTICAL);
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            var child = new cc.Node();
            child.setContentSize(cc.size(w, h));
            this.createSubScrollView(child);
            child.setPosition(cc.p(0, h * i));
            container.addChild(child);
        }
        var f1 = container.getAnchorPoint();
        container.setPosition(cc.p(0, 0));
        this.addChild(container);
        return true;
    },`

```
createSubScrollView: function(container) {
    var size = container.getContentSize();
    var count = 10;
    var w = size.width / 4;;
    var h = size.height;
    var c_container = new cc.Node();
    c_container.setContentSize(cc.size(w * count, h));
    var scroll = new cc.ScrollView(size, c_container);
    scroll.setDirection(cc.SCROLLVIEW_DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL);
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var child = new cc.Node();
        child.setContentSize(cc.size(w, h));
        var color = i % 2 == 0 ? cc.color.RED : cc.color.GREEN;
        var c = new cc.LayerColor(color, w, h);
        child.addChild(c);
        var label = new cc.LabelTTF("" + i, "Arial", 20);
        label.setPosition(cc.p(w * 0.5, h * 0.5));
        child.addChild(label);
        child.setPosition(cc.p(w * i, 0));
        scroll.addChild(child);
    }
    container.addChild(scroll);
},
});
```

add here is what it acts
[image: here is what it acts]

Comment: ok, we will can scroll rows (any rows will be in horizontal scrollviews), but how we can scroll columns?

Comment: @Gene i put the code on, both the vertical scrollview and horizontal child scrollview can scroll. it seems to work perfectly

Comment: Its works good for rows, but if we try vertical scrolling, all columns scroll. I can't scroll single column.

Comment: @Gene now i see what you exactly want. i think the only way is make every cell an independent node, and use touch event listener to change their position.